# How to make div scalable by using percentage in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a question about scalable div. I know we could do something like

```
<pre>
    <code>
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 98%;
        }
    </code>
</pre>
```

And that would make the image scalable when resizing the windows. But how do I achieve the same effect in plain div? I want to specify min-width and min-height as well. So, I want the div to be 450x300 regarding the content inside the div, but when the windows is resized the div needs to be able to reflect its size to the windows as well. However, when I do something like

```
<pre>
    <code>
    div {
        min-width: 450px;
        min-height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </code>
</pre>
```

It doesn't work as I suspect for all browsers as well. Please suggest me to solve this problem.

**Updated**
Here is my code example http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/Xfpp7/

What I'm trying to do is to have to div of "Some text" has the same size as the image regardless of how big the image is. And when you resize the windows the "Some Text" shrinks or grows in the same rate as the image. Not sure if this is possible at all in plain CSS, HTML. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem you have? That the content overflows out of the div, or what?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain the problem, the problem I had was that the div doesn't shrink beyond 450x300. I understand that because I specify the min height and width. But what I really like is to have a div 450x300 in normal screen, but when I look it in iPad or iPhone or just resize the screen the div will reflect as well.

Comment: In that case, you need max-width instead of min-width. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you provide the context for your underlying problem? Why are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks Alerty, I've updated my question already and posted the code example.

Comment: Who marks these questions down? WTF!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, two potential problems:

- You have a typo in your min-height
- Did you specify the height of the container of the div too? For instance, if the div is directly in `body`, you must give the body a specific height, of the browser won't know what it is.

**Edit:**
To answer your comment, if you want the div to be 450 pixels wide on large screens, but to shrink when the screen is smaller, you need `max-width` instead of `min-width`.

Comment: Hi My Lister, Thanks for your answer, I've also updated my question to show the code example already. :-)

Comment: OK, so you want the div to have the same height as some img that is located somewhere else in the document tree... Stupid question of course, but can't you just put the img in the div? Otherwise, it won't work unless you give them both the same height (in pixels) in the CSS.